# matplotlib: axes border and tick mark/label locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

The end result I'm attempting to achieve is to have a "thicker" black boarder around my plot, along xmin, xmax, ymin, & ymax. I've tried a couple of different things (such as just drawing a rectangle on the plot, see below), but I have not been able to achieve the desired results for a few reasons.

Because I cannot just use the spines (I've set 2 of them to always be at 0), I need to add some other line or rectangle to create the desired border.

By default the first and last tick labels overhang the axes. I "overcame" this by changing the horizontal or vertical alignment, but they could still use some more padding. I know this is possible, but requires a transform and is a bit clunky.

Now I'd like to remove the first and last tick marks on both axis. This is because given the way the rectangle is drawn it is always inside the plot area, but the first and last tick mark are always outside it, regardless of how thick the rectangle is. Making the rectangle thicker only causes it to overlap the first and last tick label more, which the actual tick mark remains outside the rectangle.

Any other suggestions on how to achieve this kind of border while always maintaining an axis at 0, 0 would be welcomed. That is the overall desired result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

X = np.random.randint(low=-9, high=9, size=10)
Y = np.random.randint(low=-9, high=9, size=10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()[0], ha='left')
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()[-1], ha='right')
plt.setp(ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels()[0], va='bottom')
plt.setp(ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels()[-1], va='top')
patPlotBorder = ax.add_artist(Rectangle((-10, -10), 20, 20, fill=False, color='k', linewidth=2))
ax.grid(True)
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
ax.scatter(X, Y, c="b", marker="o", s=40)
plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter with Axis at 0, 0 and Border]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing much of your code, you can set the `clip_on` to `False`, such that the complete rectangle is shown.

```
border = Rectangle((-10, -10), 20, 20, fill=False, color='k', linewidth=3, clip_on=False)
ax.add_artist(border)
```

[image]

Since the gridlines are shown above the axes content, you have some grey line within the rectangle border.

---

Alternatively, you can use two axes. One with all the content and the modified spine positions etc., and one where you just make the spines bold and remove all the rest.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.randint(low=-9, high=9, size=10)
Y = np.random.randint(low=-9, high=9, size=10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2.patch.set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False, labelleft=False, labelbottom=False)
for _, sp in ax2.spines.items():
    sp.set_linewidth(3)

ax.axis([-10, 10, -10, 10])
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()[0], ha='left')
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()[-1], ha='right')
plt.setp(ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels()[0], va='bottom')
plt.setp(ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels()[-1], va='top')

ax.grid(True)
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
ax.scatter(X, Y, c="b", marker="o", s=40)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: An excellent response, as always. Thanks. 2 follow up questions though. First, I'm actually creating the plot as a figure to embed in a Tkinter window. Given this fact, I'm not sure how to add a second axis to the same plot/subplot. If I specify `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)` (ax1 is already subplot(111)) I get a warning and neither axis shows up. How would I have 2 axes on a single subplot in this case? Second, any thoughts on how to easily pad the first and last tick label location? I've seen only 1 example and it wasn't very clean or clear. Thanks again.

Comment: You're already adding some padding to the first/last ticklabel, right? Concerning subplots, make sure they have a different label, `ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="blablubb1")`, `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="blablubb2")`

Comment: After looking through the docs a bit I noticed that you can specify a "duplicate" axes or subplot where one already exists, but something in the definition must be unique. It seems it's standard to use a different `label **kwarg` to do this, so by specifying `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, label='ax2')` it works exactly as shown in your answer. Still not sure if this is the best/correct way to do this or how to handle the tick label padding issue.

Comment: I haven't added padding to any of the ticklabels, I so far I just changed the justification using `ha='left'`, etc. I saw another SO post where someone added padding on top of the justifying to give some white space between the edge of the plot and the label, but I can't find it now. All I remember is it required some kind of special Transform.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the individual grid lines by calling `get_{x|y}gridlines()`. Each grid line is an object of [type `Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html), and you can change any of their properties, [such as thickness, color, etc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html?highlight=ine2d#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle).

```
ax.get_xgridlines()[0].set_linewidth(5)
ax.get_xgridlines()[-1].set_linewidth(5)
ax.get_ygridlines()[0].set_linewidth(5)
ax.get_ygridlines()[-1].set_linewidth(5)
```

[image]